# How to read flume config file from ftp location

Tags: hadoop, flume

I have retrieved tweets using flume 
`flume-ng agent --conf ./conf/ -f /etc/flume-ng/conf/flume.conf -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n TwitterAgent`. Here my path for flume confg is `/etc/flume-ng/conf/flume.conf` . Right now i need to read file from Ftp location  say ftp://192.168.1.11/Files/flume.conf. I have passed query as `flume-ng agent --conf ftp://192.168.1.11/Files/flume.conf -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n TwitterAgent`. I am getting this error java.lang.NullPointerException for above command , is there any solution to read files from ftp location for running flume command

Comment: Assuming this could work, does the FTP need credentials?

Comment: I have not set any credentials , created ftp to access as anonymous